# How to echo arguments in loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, arguments

I have a bash that should be run in this way:

```
./script.sh <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>...<argn>
```

I want to show these args in my bash:

```
<arg3> <arg4> ... <argn>
```

So I wrote this bash:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#-3; i++ ))
do
    echo $((3+i))
done
```

but it shows me number of args.

How can I put `#` in order to see my real args?

Thanks

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store all arguments in a BASH array and then use them for processing later:

```
args=( "$@" )
for (( i=2; i<${#args[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo "arg # $((i+1)) :: ${args[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show arguments starting from arg3, you can simply use

```
echo "${@:3}" # OR
printf "%s\n" "${@:3}"
```

If you really want to show argument indices, use

```
for (( i=3; i < $#; i++)); do 
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

A minimal solution that displays the desired arguments without the math:

```
shift 2
for word
do
  echo ${word} 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @anubhava's solution of storing the arguments in an array, but to make your original code work, you could use `eval`:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)); do
    eval echo "\$$i"
done
```

Comment: Do you mean with a C-style for loop?

Comment: with c style and and `-3` that I wrote..thank you, my problem is: `echo $((3+i))`

Comment: `echo ${!i}` is a much better method of performing indirect parameter expansion in `bash` than using `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

After your all good answers I found this solution that works well for my thread:

```
ARG=( $(echo "${@:3}") )
for (( i=1; i<=$#-3; i++ ))
do
    echo ${ARG[i]}
done
```

Comment: There's no need to post a separate answer if you accept another.